# SELECT returns data but UPDATE gives Affected rows: 0

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Here's the data:

```
CREATE TABLE `Charlies_Sierra_Papa` (
  `Mike` int(5) default NULL,
  `cpf` char(11) default NULL,
  `idFoxtrot` int(3) default NULL,

) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=254098 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Charlies_Sierra_Papa` VALUES ('1', '12345678910', '12');
INSERT INTO `Charlies_Sierra_Papa` VALUES ('2', '11121314157', '12');
INSERT INTO `Charlies_Sierra_Papa` VALUES ('3', '57585960610', '12');


CREATE TABLE `Charlies` (
  `idCharlie` int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cpf` varchar(11) NOT NULL default ''
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idCharlie`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cpf` (`cpf`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idCharlie` (`idCharlie`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=264670 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Charlies` VALUES ('1', '12345678910');
INSERT INTO `Charlies` VALUES ('2', '11121314157');
INSERT INTO `Charlies` VALUES ('3', '57585960610');


CREATE TABLE `Mike` (
  `Mike` int(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `idCharlie` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Mike`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idCharlie` (`idCharlie`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12043 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Mike` VALUES ('00001', '51214');
INSERT INTO `Mike` VALUES ('00002', '174135');
INSERT INTO `Mike` VALUES ('00003', '203553');
```

And here are the SELECT and the UPDATE:

```
UPDATE Charlies_Sierra_Papa AS csp, Charlies AS Cha, Mike_oc AS Mik
SET csp.cpf = cast(Cha.cpf AS char(11))
WHERE csp.cpf = Cha.cpf
AND Cha.idCharlie = Mik.idCharlie
AND csp.Mike = Mik.Mike
AND csp.idFoxtrot = 16 


SELECT * FROM Charlies_Sierra_Papa AS csp, Charlies AS Cha, Mike_oc AS Mik
/*SET csp.cpf = cast(Cha.cpf AS char(11))*/
WHERE csp.cpf = Cha.cpf
AND Cha.idCharlie = Mik.idCharlie
AND csp.Mike = Mik.Mike
AND csp.idFoxtrot = 16
```

my problem is: the SELECT returns the expected values, but the UPDATE gives me an annoying "Affected rows: 0" when I run it.

Any clues?

Comment: How many rows were *actually* changed in the `UPDATE`, i.e., had different values after the `UPDATE` statement occurs?  According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), "`UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed.`"

Comment: Don't use implicit SQL joins, use explicit join syntax: `UPDATE Charlies_Sierra_Papa csp INNER JOIN Charlies Cha ON (csp.cpf = Cha.cpf) INNER JOIN Mike_oc Mik ON (Cha.idCharlie = Mik.idCharlie AND csp.Mike = Mik.Mike)
SET csp.cpf = cast(Cha.cpf AS char(11))
WHERE csp.idFoxtrot = 16`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a trivial error:

I'm trying to UPDATE csp.cpf = Cha.cpf
but I'm also tying csp.cpf = Cha.cpf
so, no rows updated and no cigar.